# How to get search result for a small dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, search-engine, huggingface-transformers, sentence-transformers

I have data set which consists of 20 doctors and their expertise(mental health). In the below image you can see the two doctors name and their expertise -
[image]

User needs to query and get the recommended doctors name as search result.
For example: Search query = "I am worried about my aging parents" then out put= doctors name those who has expertise do deal with aging issue.
I have tried with sentence transformer using 'all-mpnet-base-v2 ' pre trained transfer model and using cosine similarity to get the ranking, but the search results are not good .

What would be correct strategy to deal with this kind of problem ?